# Uploading 2 images in rails using two field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form for a blog, and I would like to have two field for images. One image being the cover (in Show) and another image will serve as a preview (in index). 
My form looks as follow:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @blog, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
<%= t :Choose_File_for_cover %> <%= f.file_field :image_path, id: "avatar-upload2", required: true %>
<img id="img_prev3" width="100%" height=200 src="#" alt="your image" class="img-thumbnail hidden"/>

<%= t :Choose_File_for_homepage %> <%= f.file_field :homepagepic, id: "avatar-upload3", required: true %>
<%= f.hidden_field :image_path_cache %>
<%= f.hidden_field :homepagepic_cache %>
<%= f.actions do %>
<%= f.action :submit, :as => :input %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

My model looks like:

```
class Blog < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  acts_as_taggable
  mount_uploader :image_path, BlogUploader
  mount_uploader :homepagepic, BlogcoverUploader
end
```

It works well when I only have the `image_path` (the cover), but when I add a new field for `homepagepic`, i get a `ROLLBACK` at validation.

Can someone help me on how to select files  through two separate fields on the same form please.
Thank you

Comment: Hi @FrankyDoul, It is advisable to put a little more detail on the environment, such as the versions of the gems you use, the error that appears in the console, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've provided is very sparse and it would be helpful to see a little bit more (e.g. the controller and the uploader).

I can, however, hazard a guess: `image_path` is an existing helper method provided by Rails (see https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-image_path). I have absolutely no idea what happens when you use this as a name for a form field. It could also be because you declare your submit button to be an input (I've only ever seen and used `as: :button` for `f.action :submit`).

So overall, I would pick the following approach:

- rename your upload fields to `cover_image` and the other one to `preview_image` (that's what you've described in your posts as their respective purpose, so you should name them accordingly)
- change the submit to a `button` and remove all the noise from your template and start with the bare minimum: the two upload fields and nothing else (see sample code below – note that I haven't tested it but it should work or be very close to working)
- after that works, start adding back the noise (i.e. the translations, the cache fields etc.)

Test that it still works after every step. If you can write a Capybara test, do that – otherwise test it manually.

If you have questions, feel free to ask.

---

```
<%= semantic_form_for @blog, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :cover_image %>
  <%= f.file_field :preview_image %>

  <%= f.actions do %>
    <%= f.action :submit, as: :button %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

```rb
class Blog < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  acts_as_taggable

  mount_uploader :preview_image, BlogUploader
  mount_uploader :cover_image, BlogcoverUploader
end
```

Comment: Hi Clemens, I did exactly that, nothing more, and it worked! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As the previous poster said it's hard to debug your code without all the pieces to the puzzle. A `ROLLBACK` is happening because one or more validations failed.

Any time you have a `ROLLBACK` you can add a `!` to the `create` or `update` method being called on the object being rolled back and ActiveRecord will throw an error telling you why the `ROLLBACK` happened instead of failing gracefully.

Once you know why your object isn't persisting you can check the params of the controller action that form is submitting to. Perhaps you forgot to whitelist a param via strong params?